# Automatically generate multiple row entries for a single entry in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data for staff on various projects. I'd like to create a simple timeline for each staff member on each project. To explain this I have the following image where I have hardcoded the data from AB1 onwards to show how I'd like to present the data from the staffing allocation on the left.

[image: All Staff Project Allocation]

I'm looking for a way to gather all the projects together for each employee in to AC and show their timeline with an associated colour based on their discipline - I imagine this part will have to be created with some formatting rules. Is it possible to create this with one function in AB2 or a combination of a function in AB2 and AD2 such that it automatically builds the table based on new entries being added to different projects in the left hand data?

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have access to beta channel? Post your data as text table so that we can copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in AB2:

```
=IF(A2:A20="","",IF(XLOOKUP(A2:A20,A2:A20,ROW(A2:A20))=ROW(A2:A20),A2:A20,""))
```

and this in AD2:

```
=IF((E2:E20<DATE(YEAR(AD1:AO1),MONTH(AD1:AO1)+1,1))*(H2:H20>=AD1:AO1),A2:A20,"")
```

and this for the conditional formatting rule:

```
=($E2<DATE(YEAR(AD$1),MONTH(AD$1)+1,1))*($H2>=AD$1)*($C2="Programming")
```

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Similarly for the other CF rules.

If you need to copy the projects, it's just

```
=IF(D2:D20="","",D2:D20)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion which does work , however, as you can see from the following image, it is showing names in the other cells too. Is there both a way to stop this and also set the formula up such that it expands based on the number of entries in the table on the left and is also not fixed to the end of the year but instead will complete the rows for the duration of the project, no matter how long it is?

https://i.imgur.com/XknRQvh.jpg

Additionally, is there a way to display the projects into column AC as with my initial image example?

Comment: Yes, I hadn't picked up on the fact that column F was blank and so the start and end dates were in columns E and H not F and H. This really emphasises the wisdom of posting data in the form of text that can be copied rather than getting contributors to re-type it from an image. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The are perhaps four ways that you might explore to make this more dynamic (1) Use whole-column references like A:A. This works well in google sheets but is likely to be pretty slow in Excel. (2) Simply extend the range of the formulas to a number of rows that you're unlikely to exceed, say 1000. (3) Count the number of rows containing data and use index for the end of each range, like a2:index(A:A,counta(A:A)) (4) Possibly the best way, use a table for your data in columns A:H. For the dates starting in AD1, you could generate a sequence of dates from Jan-20 to the maximum date in your data.

Comment: Hey Tom, That works great for clearing up the names thanks and I'll apply one of your suggested methods for the duration too - apologies for not pasting in the data too, I'll make sure to do that in future. I'm still missing the projects data in the projects column AC though, is there anything I need to do to get this to work too?

Comment: That's good. The projects list should work with the last formula that I put in the answer, it's just a simple reference to column D - the if statement is needed because otherwise blanks in column D will appear as zeroes.

Comment: Just didn’t see the If at the bottom of the answer, think that’s a sign to call it a day. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi Tom, I realised a slight problem and I was wondering if you know a solution to it. If I delete a table row from the left table it leaves the data in the new data on the right. Is there a way to ensure all the cells from AB onwards are clear of data and formatting prior to the functions running to fill them?

Comment: If you look at the conditional formatting rules, you can see that it's splitting the rule into two separate rules when you delete a row from the left table. Don't know the solution off the top of my head - will have to get back to you on that one.

Comment: Hm it its a known issue with conditional formatting and subsequent deletion of rows - see discussion here for example https://superuser.com/questions/1720372/prevent-excel-conditional-formatting-from-fragmenting-when-deleting-row. I'm sorry I can't offer anything very constructive at the moment except to just clear the information in the row rather than deleting it, then refresh the CF rule at intervals. BTW I did realise that I had the CF rule as an array formula which was unnecessary, will put in a revised CF rule.

Comment: Hi Tom, 

The modification to the CF rule has broken it here. It changes the colour of the cells in AD1, AE1 (so writing over the date row), AF2, and AG3,AH3,AI3. So staggered up by one row. Any ideas?

Comment: I felt the clear contents question needed asking separately so I created a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/73529107/19839348

Comment: Think you must have altered the 'applies to' range. Will add a screenshot of the CF manager to my answer.

Comment: Hey Tom, After adjusting just the programming conditional formatting to the newly suggested method and adjusting the range I end up with the following - https://imgur.com/NoviEWH

Comment: Oh dear. Maybe start with the basic formula =($E2<DATE(YEAR(AD$1),MONTH(AD$1)+1,1))*($H2>=AD$1)*($C2="Programming") in an empty cell and make sure it evaluates to 1 (Bob is active in January). If not, step through it with evaluate formula and work out where it's going wrong. Also check that the name manager entry looks like my screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

As per below screenshot formulas i have used. For coloring and hiding duplicate names you have to use conditional formatting.

```
E2=UNIQUE(A2:B17)
G1=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SORT(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(C2:C17),MONTH(C2:C17),1),0))))
G2=XLOOKUP(1,($C$2:$C$17>=DATE(YEAR(G$1),MONTH(G$1),1))*($C$2:$C$17<=G$1)*($B$2:$B$17=$F2)*($A$2:$A$17=$E2),$A$2:$A$17,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Unfortunately using UNIQUE(A2:B17)outputs the unique names and the role on consecutive rows. Do you know how I modify this for my data whilst whilst also supporting the ability for the table on the left to expand - at the moment it's fixed to A2:A17. So I end up with -

Bob Senior Programmer
Dave Mid Level Programmer
Peter Senior Programmer
etc

Comment: The second part in my example is displaying the months the staff member is on the project, in your example, it's only showing the first full month they're on the project and not every month up until the end month. It's also using fixed data so there's no scope for the data on the left to expand and the new table on the right to automatically update. Is there anyway to adjust this or does it need a different approach?