# Automatically clear contents and formatting prior to functions operating in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On the left in the image I have a list of employees assigned to various projects with diffent start and end dates. On the right I have a timeline that is auto generated from the table on the left, showing when each employee is on a given project with some conditional formatting to denote what discipline they are.

However, there is a problem, if I delete a row from the middle of the data on the left or add one in the middle the timeline on the right is broken because eroneous data is left behind from the time the functions ran without the entry removed. Is there a way to automatically clear contents in all cells from AB2 onwards prior to the functions running?

The functions to generate the timeline on the right are as follows -

AB2 contains =IF(A2:A20="","",IF(XLOOKUP(A2:A20,A2:A20,ROW(A2:A20))=ROW(A2:A20),A2:A20,""))

AC2 contains =IF(D2:D20="","",D2:D20)

AD1 contains =EDATE(E2, SEQUENCE(1, 50, 0))

AD2 contains =IF((E2:E20<DATE(YEAR(AD1:AO1),MONTH(AD1:AO1)+1,1))*(H2:H20>=AD1:AO1),A2:A20,"")

Conditional Formatting =($E1:$E19<DATE(YEAR(AD$1:AO$1),MONTH(AD$1:AO$1)+1,1))*($H1:$H19>=AD$1:AO$1)*($C1:$C19="Programming") with another 3 rules for QA, Art, Production, and set to apply on =$AD:$XX.

[image: Clear Contents Issues]

The data from the table on the left is as follows -

Employee    Role    Discipline  Project Name    Start Date  Start Year  End Date
Bob Senior Programmer   Programming Project 1   01/01/2020  2020    28/02/2020
Bob Senior Programmer   Programming Project 2   01/03/2020  2020    31/03/2020
Bob Senior Programmer   Programming Project 3   01/04/2020  2020    30/06/2020
Dave    Mid Level Programmer    Programming Project 1   01/02/2020  2020    28/02/2020
Dave    Mid Level Programmer    Programming Project 3   01/03/2020  2020    31/07/2020
Peter   Senior Programmer   Programming Project 1   01/01/2020  2020    31/01/2020
Peter   Senior Programmer   Programming Project 2   01/04/2020  2020    31/05/2020
Jack    Junior Programmer   Programming Project 1   01/02/2020  2020    30/06/2020
Richard Senior Artist   Art Project 1   01/03/2020  2020    30/04/2020
Richard Senior Artist   Art Project 2   01/05/2020  2020    30/09/2020
Rodney  Lead QA QA  Project 1   01/03/2020  2020    30/06/2020
Chris   Senior Producer Production  Project 1   01/01/2020  2020    30/08/2020
Roger   QA  QA  Project 1   01/01/2020  2020    30/04/2020
Roger   QA  QA  Project 2   01/05/2020  2020    31/05/2020
Roger   QA  QA  Project 3   01/06/2020  2020    30/06/2020
Wesley  Mid Level Programmer    Programming Project 1   01/02/2020  2020    31/05/2020
Wesley  Mid Level Programmer    Programming Project 2   01/06/2020  2020    31/07/2020

I suspect this will need some VBA. The order of events I am looking for is

1. user adds/removes an entry on the table to the left
2. Contents but not functions are cleared from AB onwards
3. Formatting is cleared from AB onwards
4. All functions in AB2, AC2, AD1, AD2 run
5. Conditional formatting runs

If VBA is the solution, can this run on an the modification of the table on the left, perhaps copying the functions out of AB2,AC2,AD1,AD2, clearing the contents and formatting then putting the functions back in to those cells and running them? I have no idea how to do this, it's just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by inconsistent column and row fixing in the conditional formatting formula. Try the following amendment:

```
=($E1<DATE(YEAR(AD$1),MONTH(AD$1)+1,1))*($H1>=AD$1)*($C1="Programming")
```

Moreover, you can shorten the date reference with the EOMONTH() function:

```
=($E1<=EOMONTH(AD$1,0))*($H1>=AD$1)*($C1="Programming")
```

Comment: Thanks Dattel, The 2nd function needs parenthesis and * =($E1<=EOMONTH(AD$1,0)*($H1>=AD$1))*($C1="Programming"). The first likely needs the fix too. This doesn't fix it though. The order of operation I'd like, 1. user removes or adds a row in to the middle of the table on the left, ClearContents(AB2:XX) and Clear formatting (AB2:XX) would need to run to ensure old data is cleared, run all the 4 functions in my question and then the conditional formatting. I'm starting to suspect it's going to need some VBA although clearing cells prior to writing data seems an obvious thing to want to do.

Comment: Hi Dattel, I have now added a clearer explanation on how I'd like the data to be manipulated at the bottom of my question above.

Comment: I replicated your table and now understand the problem.
Yes, what you are looking for would require vba. Unless, instead of inserting/deleting cells only to the data table on the left, you insert/delete a full row in the sheet.
Since you are using array formulas in columns AB, AC and AD, those will automatically extend accordingly. That will fix your problem without vba if ok for you

Comment: Hey Dattel, I was actually considering moving the data from AB onwards in to a separate sheet. However, if I can't find an elegant solution then deleting/adding an entire row does provide a pretty clean alternative, thanks for the suggestion.